# Error; Cross-Domain iframe failing when it attempts to access property of element in parent window

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have a a link on click of which I open a div as a pop up. While opening the content, I first load a page from similar domain into an iFrame in that div.
On the basis of some conditions, that page further redirects to an another cross domain page. Now there are some dynamic properties being used in that page which are trying to access the property of the parent window but due to some Cross Domain rules, we get the JavaScript error :- "Error: Permission denied to access property 'ug'".

It is trying to access this property through window.parent.ug and here the parent element is my page.

Is there any work around for this like either we can inject some JavaScript function into our iFrame to handle this or something else.

Comment: Is this correct: You are opening an iFrame that opens another (cross-domain) iFrame that needs to reach it's parent's objects. (?)

Comment: No, I am opening a cross domain page into an iFrame in a div on my page.

Comment: And the new page needs what from it's parent? do you have a live link?

Comment: this is so abstract, you may as well be speaking chinese, please post some code with your question to clear up the mass confusion you're creating

Answer (score 0):

a cross-domain request will produce an error, I don't think any browser will allow this in the 21st century. . What that page is trying to do is load an attribute 'ug' from one of the elements in it's parent window. . .what that attribute is? you'll have to figure that out yourself, unless there's a tutorial that you were referencing while doing what you were doing, then I suggest you refer to it and go over the details once more, because you're obviously missing something.

you cannot change the contents of an iframe from the parent window for security reasons, modern browsers will not allow this. hackers would use such functionality to exploit users.

from what the error says, something like this is happenning in that iframe;

```
var parentWindowTextElementsUGProperty = window.parent.getElementById('#myInputTextElement').ug;
```